# Why is this program crashing after it outputs a few elements

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int sizer = (rand() % 15) + 2;
    int nenad[sizer];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer;i++)
        nenad[i] = (rand() % 15) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer;i++)
        cout << nenad[i] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer;i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1;i < sizer;j++)
        {
            if (nenad[i] > nenad[j])
            {
                int temp = nenad[i];
                nenad[i] = nenad[j];
                nenad[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The biggest elements are : " << nenad[sizer-1] << " and " << nenad[sizer-2] << endl;
```

The program adds a random amount of random numbers to an array. While they're being outputed the program crashed. why?

Comment: `int nenad[sizer];` ... runtime sized stack array? Am I confused or is that not really C++?

Comment: @MartinBa `gcc` extension most likely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730101/when-are-variable-length-arrays-legal

Comment: @MartinBa, It won't be standard until C++1y.

Comment: By the way, use `std::swap` instead of making your own. Also use `std::generate_n` to fill it with random values, and `std::partial_sort` to sort the largest two elements.

Comment: if it's homework for an intro level class, they don't let you use the cstdlib sorting and number generation stuff

Answer (score 10):

Your loop end condition seems curious, I presume

```
for (int j = i + 1;i < sizer;j++)
```

should really be

```
for (int j = i + 1;j < sizer;j++)
```

Comment: @MartinBa I've done this so many times myself that my brain is close to overlaying squiggly lines where I need to look :)

Answer (score 3):

also your loop conditions are broken. should be comparing j < sizer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizer;i++)
{
    // we don't check j here
    for (int j = i + 1;i < sizer;j++)
    {
        //j can exceed the size of nenad and read from a bad address
        if (nenad[i] > nenad[j])
        {
            int temp = nenad[i];
            // same as above
            nenad[i] = nenad[j];
            // or write to a bad address
            nenad[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing you should **really** consider using / doing is making use of **valgrind**. It will catch this for you when our eye's can't.