# memory leak heap and stack compilation issue C

Tags: malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

i've  got a qestion, i'm using sourgery c++ toolchain, and the compiler leave me to write this sentence:

```
for(i=0;i<size_of_categories;i++){

    size_t size_of_tmp = sizeof(char) * (HOSTLINK_CONFIG_STRING_MAX_LEN * (categories[i].key_len));

    char tmp[size_of_tmp];
    memset(tmp,0,(size_of_tmp));    
    get_hostlink_count[i]++;

    if(categories[i].time == get_hostlink_count[i]){

        if(format == CSV){

            csv_this_category_values(categories,i,tmp,size_of_tmp);
            strncat(buffer,tmp,buff_len);

        }else if (format == JSON){

            xi_json_this_category_values(categories,i,tmp,size_of_tmp);
            js_this_cat = json_loads(tmp,JSON_DECODE_ANY,NULL);
            json_array_extend(js_arr,js_this_cat);

            json_array_clear(js_this_cat);
            json_decref(js_this_cat);
        }

        get_hostlink_count[i] = 0;

    }
    //Free(tmp);
}
```

My issue is this sentece alloc memory in stack or in the heap? This could cause memory leak because is made in a for loop?
Is this equivalent to make a malloc and at the end of the loop a Free?

```
size_t size_of_tmp = sizeof(char) * (HOSTLINK_CONFIG_STRING_MAX_LEN * (categories[i].key_len));

    char tmp[size_of_tmp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your not doing any `malloc`s, there won't be a memory leak in this particular piece of code. However, you can't declare your `tmp` array with a non-constant size. That is, you can't say `char tmp[size_of_tmp]` with `size_of_tmp` not being constant (which it isn't because it depends on `categories[i].key_len`).

What you *can* do is to use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate memory for your array on the heap like this

```
char *tmp = (char*)malloc(size_of_tmp);
```

or this

```
char *tmp = (char*)calloc(size_of_tmp, sizeof(char));
```

`calloc` already initializes all of the allocated memory to zero, so you don't have to use `memset`.

If you want to avoid memory leaks you have to `free` the allocated `tmp` array at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: You _can_ declare an array of a variable non-const size in C++.

Comment: and in C++ this use stack?

Comment: @mah You sure? I mean, it looks like it have been in the standard, but apparently  

> no C++ standard ever accepted VLAs from C99, so technically the fact of admitting VLAs in C++ is a g++ extension.  

see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5730286/2640170) ...

Comment: @user2387829 there's never a guarantee of a local being placed on the stack; the compiler is free to place it where it wants (and since it's a variable of automatic scope, the compiler is required to reclaim the memory when it's out of scope).

Comment: @PoByBolek I think you're correct that VLA is just a gnu extension. It's a confusing topic though. As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays states, the standard reads "C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the C programming language as specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (hereinafter referred to as the C standard). In addition to the facilities provided by C, C++ provides...", suggesting that if it's in C it's in C++, however that page also states "... doesnt mean that any and everything in c99 is in c++11". I dunno.

Comment: @mah I didn't even know that there were VLAs in C/C++ until today... I find them kind of creepy though.